Convert Vertical 1D Array Horizontally
Why does temp contains a horizontal 1D array? While temp2 contains a vertical 1D array? How do I transpose temp2 horizontally?

I'm new to coding and I didn't understand some of the explanations I found online.
function testfunction(){
  const home = ss.getSheetByName('HOME');

  let temp = [];
  let selectedLot = home.getRange('C6').getDisplayValue();
  let name = home.getRange('C9').getDisplayValue();
  let term = home.getRange('C10').getDisplayValue();
  let agnt = home.getRange('C11').getDisplayValue();
  temp.push(selectedLot,name,term,agnt);

  let temp2 = [];
  let date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"Asia/Manila","M/d/yyyy");
  let area = home.getRange('F8').getDisplayValue();
  let lotcode = home.getRange('F9').getDisplayValue();
  let reportNum = home.getRange('F10').getDisplayValue();
  let payorpayee = home.getRange('F7').getDisplayValue();
  let account = home.getRange('F5').getDisplayValue();
  let particular = home.getRange('F6').getDisplayValue();
  let amount = home.getRange('F11').getValue();
  let type = home.getRange('F12').getDisplayValue();
  temp2.push(date,area,lotcode,reportNum,payorpayee,account,particular,amount,type);

  console.log(temp)
  console.log(temp2)
}


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand Why does temp contains a horizontal 1D array? While temp2 contains a vertical 1D array? How do I transpose temp2 horizontally?. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

https://i.sstatic.net/mdRGTliD.png Here is a screenshot of the results.

Thank you for replying. About i.sstatic.net/mdRGTliD.png Here is a screenshot of the results., when I saw the image you provided, might you be saying the visibility of the log? If my understanding is correct, both arrays temp and temp2 are a 1-dimensional array. I think that the difference of the visibility of log is due to the specification of the script editor. For example, you might have wanted console.log(JSON.stringify(temp)) and console.log(JSON.stringify(temp2))?
If my understanding of your question is not correct, I apologize.

temp is not a "horizontal array". temp2 is not a "vertical array". In fact, there is no such thing as a "vertical" or a "horizontal" array. They are just "arrays". Any appearance of being "vertical" or "horizontal" is because of the source of the underlying data. The question asks: How do I transpose temp2 horizontally? Would you please edit the question to include an example of temp2 as a horizontal array.

There is no issue here. It's just the way it's displayed because the second array is longer (has more elements) than the first. They are just the same in terms of dimension. I think what you meant in horizontal and vertical array applies in 2d arrays when accessing cells in google sheets (because it uses 2d arrays). For example, [[1,2,3]] is a "horizontal" since it will have one row of cells while [[1],[2],[3]] is a "vertical" since it will have one column of cells.

It's a matter of available space to display the logs. The Array assigned to temp has fewer elements than temp2.
Increase the window size or reduce the window zoom to make more space available for displaying the logs. Please remember that the logs are intended to display messages that help you track code execution and debugging.
You might insert spaces and break lines. Also, it will benefit you to learn about JSON.stringify. Briefly, this method converts a JavaScript object into a string.
